# "HTTP:400 project is required" error while creating JIRA alert using Yelp ElastAlert library

Tags: jira, elastalert

While creating JIRA alert using ElastAlert library facing issue

ERROR:root:Error while running alert jira: Error creating JIRA ticket: HTTP 400: "project is required"

Though I have configured the jira_project property

below is content of my rule.yaml cofig file.

jira_server: URL

jira_project: Test Project

jira_issuetype: Bug

jira_account_file: FilePath

jira_description: Automated Jira Ticket by ElastAlert

Comment: I haven't used elastalert yet, but I'd try with the project key instead of the project name.

Answer (score 0):

So from this discussion(https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/641) got to know that for project name, we have to enter the short name of the project, for example (jira.xyz.com/jira/browse/TP)

So the correct way to put the properties is as below:

jira_server: https://jira.xyz.com/jira

jira_project: TP

For complete example on creating email and JIRA alerts refer: http://vaibhavtupe.blogspot.com/2016/07/elasticsearch-jira-alert-and-email.html